# Google Sheets Regex removing unnecessary text

Tags: regex, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, regexp-replace

Please help me to solve this problem.

Using below formula to extract this information.

```
IFERROR(REGEXEXTRACT(A2:A,"(TRN\*.+\\|TRN\*.+\~)"))
```

I want to remove these signs from output `\` and `~`.

Here is the formula output.

```
TRN*1*6523251452*5865418282584~
TRN*1*5685952452*158615*6526352 26\
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
IFERROR(REGEXEXTRACT(A2:A,"TRN\*[^~\\]+"))
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/zzMSfN/1). Also, you may add a word boundary `\b` at the start of the pattern to make sure `TRN` is matched as a whole, standalone word, `\bTRN\*[^~\\]+`.

*Details*

- `TRN\*` - `TRN*` text
- `[^~\\]+` - one or more chars other than `~` and `\`.

Comment: I was striving for an hour to fix the problem thank you very much.